# using navigine SDK for indoor navigation app

Tags: flutter, sdk, indoor-positioning-system

so I am trying to build an indoor navigation app in Flutter and I found the https://navigine.com/developers/ which offers code in GitHub. I have created the map on their website and downloaded the SDK folder and went through all the documentation but I am still not able to make the app run
any suggestions on how to do it? or if there any SDK that will work better